# Easier proof of Hasse-Weil bound?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, upper-lower-bounds

Is there a proof for this theorem?

$Theorem$: Let $\mathbb F_q$ be a finite field of order $q$ = $p^n$, and let $C$ be an absolutely irreducible smooth projective curve defined over $\mathbb F_q$. To each such curve $C$ one can associate a genus $g$; for instance, elliptic curves have genus $1$. We can also count the cardinality $|C({\mathbb F}_q)|$ of the set $C({\mathbb F}_q)$ of ${\mathbb F}_q$-points of $C$. We now state the Hasse-Weil bound:
$\left|\,|C(\mathbb F_q)|-q-1\,\right|\leq 2g\,q^{1/2}$.

I tried reading the proof Terence Tao left on his blog, but I seem quite stumped. Is there a link for a more simple proof, or something more understandable?

Comment: How much background in algebraic geometry do you have? The usual modern approach to this theorem, as Tao mentions, is to prove the Grothendieck–Lefschetz trace formula for curves, which isn't elementary but is perhaps conceptually neater (and easier to generalize). For that matter, doesn't the Bombieri–Stepanov proof that Tao explains ([here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/the-bombieri-stepanov-proof-of-the-hasse-weil-bound/), for reference) only prove a weaker bound than Hasse–Weil?

Comment: Actually, you should provide a link to Tao's presentation in your post - is it the one that @DanielHast gives?

Comment: Sorry for being offline. Here is the link: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/hasse-weil-bound/

Comment: Oh wait nevermind. I got it.